# Antonym/Opposite of "on the morrow"

Tags: time, archaicisms

If my birthday is on the 15th August and I tidy up on August 16th I can say: "I threw a huge party and tidied up on the morrow.". But if I prepared for the party on August 12th then what do I say? "I threw a huge party which I prepared on the ......". I don't want to use "the day before". Is there another more eloquent word/phrase? Some thoughts:on the yesterday, yestern, ereyesterday.

Comment: on the day prior? using synonyms for _before_ may be a simple way to come up with a more eloquent phrase.

Comment: Maybe a native speaker here will be more confident about how strongly "on the eve" suggests just the evening and not the entire day before. (Cf. Christmas Eve and New Year's Eve?)

Comment: I seriously doubt you will find a specific word that means _three days beforehand_. The _evening_ before would indeed be the _eve_. Three days beforehand would be, well, _three days beforehand_.

Comment: Not every concept has a specific word in English. Sometimes a number of contributory concepts (like "day" or "three days", "before") have to be combined to describe exactly what's wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure if this usage is country-specific, but it is common in the United States to use the phrase "three days in advance" [of whatever the event may have been]; oerkelens's suggested "three days beforehand" is another common way to express the same idea in the U.S., just as "three days later" and "three days afterward" are for cleanups (or whatever) that don't fall within the limited purview of "the morrow."

Comment: FYI “on the morrow” sounds really silly (just so you know!) it's "dungeons and dragons" language.  (Or "led zeppelin album cover language" .. you know?)

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has yet included it in an answer:

The most obvious parallel to *on the morrow* (which is archaic and highly literary and *not* something I would recommend using in normal speech except if you’re deliberately trying to sound like someone out of a Tolkien or Shakespeare piece) is ***on the eve***.

*Eve* is slightly less archaic than *morrow*, and it is still relatively common to hear the phrase *on the eve of X* used in normal speech; so you could say that you held the party on the eve of your birthday (you had the party the night before your actual birthday).

Without the prepositional phrase *of X*, however, it becomes very archaic and stilted, just like cleaning up on the morrow is.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet for Ye Olde sound is:

> a day afore.

It also works fine with a number of days,

> We prepared for the feast three days afore, and then the feast great and true was held on Wenceslas - high noon and bright sayeth - with both hogs and maidens mud soaked - aye! - by the great Common Walls. Much revelry and tupping was had with the rear parts of hogs, and even some of the maidens...

... sort of thing.

Another Ye Olde option you have is "hence", as in *"By the yeoman, we prepared on Midden's Eve the whole day, for the party three days hence.  Aye, and three nights also true."* .. sort of thing

As I said in a comment, “on the morrow” sounds **really spectacularly silly** -- just so you know! It's "dungeons and dragons" language, or "led zeppelin album cover language" .. you know?!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider "previous" as a straightforward yet more formal option;
   "We prepared three days previous to the party"

A more antiquated choice would be "ere," as in
   "Three days ere the party we prepared."

"Foretime" could be useful if it is not required to be a specific amount of time beforehand.

In regards to "on the yesterday" and "yestern," they only infer the day before today. "Yesterweek" is another antiquated possibility or if you want to fudge it a bit you could use "three days yester" or the like.