# Word to replace "tomorrow" in a world without "day"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word meant to represent the evening, much like "tomorrow", "today", [missing word], and "tonight". I do realise that "tomorrow" doesn't actually mean "this morning", but the word I'm looking for is a sort-of replacement for "tomorrow" for a fictional world where mornings and days are a thing of the past and it is engulfed in eternal nights.

There already exists a question which asks for an antonym to the phrase "on the morrow", which I link here:
[Antonym/Opposite of "on the morrow"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202163/antonym-opposite-of-on-the-morrow), and the word "eve" came up, which would look utterly horrendous as "toeve" for my purposes.

Is there an existing word in the English language that could substitute "morrow" of "tomorrow" to be related to evening time?

Sample sentence: **What I couldn't finish tonight, I will not finish [word] either.**

Comment: Why doesn't *later* or any of its synonyms work?

Comment: I'm really looking for something specific to *next day* (*next night*, all things considered). *Later* is a lot more general, while what I'm after is "nightly tomorrow".

Comment: On planet Earth, *What I couldn't finish tonight, I will not finish **tomorrow night** either*. Or *What I couldn't finish **this evening**, I will not finish **tomorrow evening** either*. In some fictional context where there are no days and nights, it wouldn't make sense to talk about not finishing something ***tonight*** or *[this] **evening*** anyway.

Comment: You may have to coin your own term then. Tomorrow is so set and so common in usage that it means the next day generally, whether there's light or not. A speaker in the Arctic or Antarctic might find it a bit funny that *tomorrow* has no light during the winter, but AFAIK they would recognize that it refers to clock periods or to periods of activity, not to daylight.

Comment: If there is no day/night cycle, refer to another cycle. Not this clock, not this bell, not this sleep, not for three dinners, not until I have pissed nine quarts, two high tides from now. Consider asking at wordbuilding.stackexchange.com

Comment: 'Doesn't actually mean morning' I think you are under the impression that 'tomorrow' in English has something to do with the morning (which cognate wise is what many other European languages do: German Morgen/Spanish mañana = morning or tomorrow). That is not the case at all in English. 'Tomorrow' means anything about the day after today; there is no connotation at all of the morning.

Comment: @Mitch Oh, I had no idea about that - and that would pretty much solidify the right to existence of "tomorrow", I suppose? Thank you! I'm not sure whether it'd be appropriate to accept your comment as an answer because it isn't exactly what I'm after, but it closes the question alright.

Comment: @IvanT. I am hesitating to give an actual answer because I see that it is getting a number of close votes. I can only guess that those close votes are because of the misunderstanding, and also the use of 'opposite' in the title which also seems to be a misunderstanding. It seems unfair to be penalized for misunderstanding when that is exactly what you're trying to fix, but I think, now you understand that 'tomorrow night' is the word you're looking for all along.

Comment: in the future: this afternoon, this evening, tonight, tomorrow morning, tomorrow afternoon, tomorrow evening. in the past: this morning, last night, yesterday evening, yesterday afternoon, yesterday afternoon. If there's no morning.night, daylight ever, then everything would be just as it already is in English, just without aulifiers: yesterday, today, tomorrow.

Comment: This question is possibly better suited for World Building SE: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you world has no Day/Night cycle but still observes time it has to observe it based on some other cycle. Whatever that cycle is should inform the vernacular used here. If you want to be really broad with it you could use early-cycle, mid-cycle and late-cycle or some variation on that. The cycle would be the 'day' defined by whatever defines the cycles in that world. Once you have that span you could cut it into three slices and call each slice by its location in the cycle.

I don't know enough about how know how your world is structured to give any more specific feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no such thing as day or night, and if *tomorrow* is longer in use, then, barring some other fictional terminology, you have to fall back on using clock timings.

In other words (assuming this is actually accurate given the current time):

> What I couldn't finish by now, I will not finish *in twelve hours* either.

Note that I removed *tonight* from the example sentence. If *tomorrow* is meaningless, then *tonight* is probably meaningless too.